# What's the purpose of Web App Libraries folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse somehow copies jar-files, which I add to WEB-INF/lib, into that folder too.

But what's the meaning of Web App Libraries in a Eclipse Web project?

Comment: In this folder Eclipse lists jars that are in classath of your application and are not provided by server. So it has to copy them when deploying.

Comment: That folder is purely informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing gets copied there while you're developing your web app because it's not any kind of file or folder. It is instead a **container** of entries for your project's **Java Build Path**. This container makes sure the jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and any Java projects you've marked in **Deployment Assembly**  are automatically part of the project's **Java Build Path**. The jars for those projects only really need to be created when you deploy; recreating those jars for every change you make to any classes in those projects would not be a good use of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Those Jar files contains the executable `.class` files (i,e output of `.java` source files )  on which your Source files depends upon. So these files are modules from other vendors or created by you before which can be used in this project.

For example your project may depend on JDBC driver of MySQL if your are using MySQL. So this lib folder is the place where you can put this driver.